# How can hide and show information using prototype?

Tags: javascript, html, prototype

I'd like to a select box that will show information According a selection, how?

If I select option A will show info1 and if I select option B will show info2.

```
<select>
  <option>AAAAAAAAAA</option>
  <option>BBBBBBBBBB</option>
</select>    

<div id="info1" style="display:none;">
 <select>
   <option>aaaaaaaaaa</option>
   <option>aaaaaaaaaaa</option>
 </select> 
</div>    

<div id="info2" style="display:none;">
 <select>
   <option>bbbbbbbbbbb</option>
   <option>bbbbbbbbbbb</option>
 </select> 
</div>
```

- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HgqNf/)

Comment: I'm not sure if _prototype.js_ has anything special for this, just do it in vanilla e.g. `node.style.display = '';` to show and `node.style.display = 'none';` to hide where `node` is whichever `<div>` you want

Comment: I want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/LEfbX/23/ but without using jquery , just in prototype

Comment: You can build the onchange handler to set the display property based on the selected value. You do not need prototype for this.

Comment: How could be? i tried this http://jsfiddle.net/HgqNf/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a javascript function with onchange event of your select box like below:

```
<select name="select1" id="select1" onchange="showDiv()">
   <option value="A">AAAAAAAAAA</option>
   <option value="B">BBBBBBBBBB</option>
</select>
```

And write a javascript function like this:

```
document.getElementById("select1").onchange=function(){

     var value= document.getElementById("select1").value;
    //alert("Test"+value);
    if(value=="A"){
        document.getElementById("info2").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("info1").style.display="inline";


    }else if(value=="B"){
        document.getElementById("info1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("info2").style.display="inline";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("info1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("info2").style.display="none";
    }
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HgqNf/29/

Comment: Added the fiddle in the answer above please check.

Comment: @Carlitos: answers should be considered as hints for your own new research, not things that can be typed in verbatim. If you say "it doesn't work" then you're not giving any new information to someone who might be able to help. (Thus, I recommend avoiding that phrase entirely if possible - we like to say here that it is the least useful fault report possible `;-)`).